# return userdata result of ec2 with terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to create a Jenkins pipeline, which deploys an application on aws autoscaling group using user_data.

Sometimes the deployment fail, but I don't how to show the deployment result when terraform is running, especially user data script result.

So is it possible to print the user data output (script result) with terraform?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: I have never done that and I'm actually not quite sure if it's even possible, but an idea would be to write the user_data output to a file which you then output via Terraform...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Terraform EC2 data resource to extract the instances metadata including the SHA-1 userdata. https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/instance.html

```
data "aws_instance" "foo" {
instance_id = "i-instanceid"
get_user_data = true
}
```

Keep